# Advice on better way to program jquery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of social icons that when hovered over increase in width to reveal more content while the rest decrease width to keep the overall ul width the same.  I was wondering if someone could tell me if the way I did is good or if there is a better way of doing it.  I am still trying to learn jquery and its best practices.

Also everything seems to be working well except the last list item will drop down occasionally.  I'm thinking it has something to do with the hovered items width increasing at a different rate than the other items decreasing.

Here is what I have (note only facebook has content associate with it at the moment):

```
$(function() {
    $('.social-container > li').on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $('.social-container > li').stop().animate({'width':'16%'},400);
            $(this).stop().animate({'width':'50%'},400).queue(function(){
                $(this).find(".icon-placeholder").hide();
                $(this).find(".icon-link").stop().fadeIn("slow").show();
                $(this).dequeue();
            });

       },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $('.social-container > li').stop().animate({'width':'25%'},400);
            $(this).stop().animate({'width':'25%'},400);  
            $(this).find(".icon-link").stop().fadeOut("slow").hide();
            $(this).find(".icon-placeholder").show();
       }
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jfunchio/uuwdr5Ly/1/

Comment: Since you aren't grabbing any dynamic data with javascript and everything is the same width -- it might be advantageous to handle everything via CSS. li:hover with a transition of .4s

Comment: Since you're still learning I cleaned up your code a bit. Basically I store your jQuery objects in a variable so you aren't wasting resources on recreating the same jQuery object over again. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uuwdr5Ly/2/)

Comment: @Jack - Only thing I will add to your code ( it also applies to OP's original code) is i will add an overflow:hidden to the social-container class. This will take out the quick jerky effect of the list element where the last list element drops down for a fraction of a second when you move the mouse over fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to achieve all this is via css animation. I have prepared a JSFiddle for this to show the main idea: https://jsfiddle.net/uuwdr5Ly/3/

Here is the css code that make animation possible:

```
ul.social-container > li{ 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s
    transition: all 0.4s;
    width:75px;
}

ul.social-container > li:hover {width:150px}
```

Also take a look at JSFiddle because I change more css in order to make it work with your code.

Comment: the width of the ul increases when hovered as the other li elements that are not hovered on remains the same width ( we need it to shrink as well)

Comment: don't understand what you mean, from the example you show it shrink back when you hover on other li element

Comment: lets say there was another div to the right of this menu. what happens when you hover over the list item ( eg. facebook) ? the div on the right is pushed down because the width of the ul element ( collection of all your list items) increases.

Comment: case in point consider this example https://jsfiddle.net/svaidhyanath/uuwdr5Ly/5/

Comment: Yes, you are right. To solve this you will need to have enough space for grow on hover. Another way will be to change the way the css is written, so it does not affect the width of ul list.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/uuwdr5Ly/4/

You'd better use some css animations instead of jquery - it's pretty possible nowadays.

What I've done to your code?

```
.icon-link{
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
```

You can't animate an item from `display: none` to `display: block`, unfortunately - therefore you can hide it with opacity set to 0 and position absolute.

```
ul.social-container:hover li{
    width: 16%;
}

ul.social-container li:hover {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Here you can set the way how your socials will be resized on mouseover. On mouseout they will get their base 25% width. No need to write `.on('mouseover')`!

```
ul.social-container, ul.social-container li {
    transition: width .4s ease;
}

ul.social-container .icon-placeholder,
ul.social-container .icon-link {
    transition: opacity .4s ease;
}
```

And that is how you can define transitions on this elements. Always pick the one prop you're actually changing, to save some memory.

```
ul.social-container li:hover .icon-placeholder {
    opacity: 0;
}

ul.social-container li:hover .icon-link {
    opacity: 1;
    display: inline;
}
```

And that's how you're hiding-showing you icon-content!

GL!

P.S. Don't forget IE8 is dead but you still need all these prefixes (-ms, -moz, -webkit).

Comment: I went to your answer and edited the link to reflect the right link as u have shown . In future just go into your answer and correct the link as that would be more helpful to other solution seekers

Comment: Yeap, you're right - sorry I am kinda new to StackOverflow =)

Comment: no worries. welcome to SO :) we always need good helpers/coders to be around ;)